# Docker: "Unknown instruction: VIRTUALENV'

Tags: python, docker, boot2docker

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python build-essential python-dev python-pip python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-common postgresql-client -y
RUN apt-get install openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN pip install virtualenv uwsgi

ADD canonicaliser_api ~
virtualenv ~/canonicaliser_api/venv
source ~/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate
pip install -r ~/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80

CMD service nginx start
```

**Build error:**

```
...
Successfully installed virtualenv uwsgi
Cleaning up...
 ---> 0c141e23f725
Removing intermediate container d9fd3c20365d
Step 8 : ADD canonicaliser_api ~
 ---> 89b4fb40dba5
Removing intermediate container b0c1ad946fc4
Step 9 : VIRTUALENV 
Unknown instruction: VIRTUALENV
```

is it supposed to remove those containers?
Why isn't it seeing `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it supposed to remove those containers?

Yes.  If you want to keep them for some reason, pass `--rm=false` to the `docker build` command.

> Why isn't it seeing `virtualenv`?

It is seeing it, but because it's at the start of a line, it treats it like a Dockerfile instruction, but there is no "VIRTUALENV" instruction.  Presumably, you meant to put `RUN` before each line after the `ADD`:

```
ADD canonicaliser_api ~
RUN virtualenv ~/canonicaliser_api/venv

# This one needs to be a single RUN so the "source" will affect pip.
RUN source ~/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && \
        pip install -r ~/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The last line gives me a strange error: `Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt'`  But its right there...